# In Clojure passing a open file pointer into functions

Tags: clojure, io

In Conjure, I need to read in a long file, too long to slurp in, and I wish to pass the open file pointer into method, which I can call recursively, reading until it is empty.  I have found examples using open-with, but is there a way to open a file and then read from it inside of a function?  Points to examples or docs would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Is this along the lines of what you have in mind?

```
(defn process-file [f reader]
  (loop [lines (line-seq reader) acc []]
    (if (empty? lines)
      acc
      (recur (rest lines) (conj acc (f (first lines)))))))

(let [filename "/path/to/input-file"
      reader (java.io.BufferedReader. (java.io.FileReader. filename))]
  (process-file pr-str reader))
```

Note that if you `(require '[clojure.java.io :as io])` you can use `io/reader` as a shortcut for invoking `BufferedReader` and `FileReader` directly. However, using `with-open` would still be preferable - it will ensure the file is closed properly, even in the event of an exception - and you can absolutely pass the open reader to other functions from within a `with-open` block.

Here's how you could make use of `with-open` in the scenario you use in the answer you've posted, passing the reader and writer objects to a function:

```
(with-open [rdr (io/reader "/path/to/input-file")]
  (with-open [wtr (io/writer "/path/to/output-file")]
    (transfer rdr wtr)))
```

I should also note that in my example scenario it would be preferable to `map` or `reduce` over the `line-seq` but I used `loop`/`recur` since you asked about recursion.

[Here's](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.java.io) the ClojureDocs page on the `clojure.java.io` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Playing around I discovered the answer, so for any others looking, here is a version of my solution.

```
(defn transfer
  [inFile outFile]
  (.write outFile (.read inFile))
...

...
(transfer (clojure.java.io/reader "fileIn.txt)
          (clojure.java.io/writer "out.txt"))
```